# Java Multiplication with several bases

Tags: java, multiplication

Hi everyone I stuck on this homework the task is to multiply two BigInteger Numbers. I should use the base k. But the result is not right. Can someone give me a hint i think the problem is the shiftleft.

```
    public BigInteger multBaseKBit(BigInteger a, BigInteger b, int k) {
    BigInteger result = new BigInteger("0");
    BigInteger tmp = new BigInteger("0");
    for (int i = 0; i < b.bitLength();) {

        if (b.testBit(i)) {
            tmp = a;
            tmp = tmp.shiftLeft(i);
            result = result.add(tmp);
            System.out.println(result);

        }
        i = i + k;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Why do not you use `BigInteger`'s `multiply()` method?

Comment: The aim of this topic is to look for the running time from diffrent muliply algorithms

Comment: What is the problem definition?

Comment: A simple idea to accelerate the Multplikation, is
b to select a different number base by k bits each to
a new paragraph summarizing. For example, you need to k = 4
only n / 4 hexadecimal digits. Instead of n additions of partial products
you then need only n / 4 additions